# Diophantine equation exercise

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Prove **that the diophantine equation $x^4-2(y^2)=1$ has only 2 solutions**. Any hint on how to start and what to do .. I do not have a lot of experience on non linear diophantine equations and do not know how to approximate them. So far I can see that for $y=0$, $x=1$ is one solution.

Comment: Look for Pell's equation $z^2-2y^2=1$, with $z=x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

There is the following result of J. H. E. Cohn concerning the Diophantine equation 
$$
x^4-Dy^2=1.
$$
**Theorem (Cohn 1997):**
Let the fundamental solution of the equation $v^2 − Du^2 = 1$ be $a + b\sqrt{D}$. Then the only possible solutions of the above equation are given by $x^2 = a$ and $x^2 = 2a^2 − 1$; both solutions occur in only one case, $D = 1785$.

For $D=2$ we have $a=1$ so that $x^2=1$ and $y=0$. For the proof of Cohen's result, see [here](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa78/aa7847.pdf). 
For an easy proof for the case of $D=2$ see [Solutions of Diophantine equations in Natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263647/solutions-of-diophantine-equations-in-natural-numbers).

Comment: (1,0) is one solution what is the second?

Comment: What is the second solution of $x^2=1$ ?

Comment: hahahaha oh my god !!!thanks.Does the full proof covers the uniqueness of the solutions?hm..the exercise was suppose to be for homework is it possible to exist an easier answer that does not use  other theorems.Just use the basic theory  of diophantine equations?Thank you!

Comment: Yes, sorry, you are right. There is an easy solution, see the link I have included. But for general $D$ Cohn's solution seems to be the right one.