# Prove that the integers solutions to $x^4-2y^2=1$ are only $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I want to prove that the integers solutions to $x^4-2y^2=1$ are only $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$

There is a hint:

The positive primitive solutions of $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ with $y$ is even are $x=r^2-s^2, ~y=2rs,~z=r^2+s^2$. And we can use the similar proof to prove the equation.

But I don't know how to start it, anyone can help?

Comment: The title claim is false. Take $x=3$ and $y=40$. Then $x^4-2y-1=81-80-1=0$. So I assume a typo. The "corrected" equation has been solved here, too (see for example [here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-prove-that-the-Diophantine-equation-x-4-2y-2-1-has-only-the-trivial-solutions-namely-1-0-and-1-0)).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Actually there exist infinitely many solutions: $y=\frac {x^4-1}{2}$ when $x$ is odd. Could this be the original of the problem $$x^4-2y^2=1$$ or $$x^4-2y^4=1$$

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, exactly, there is a typo. Most likely $x^4-2y^2=1$  is the "corrected" equation, which is a FAQ, see for example [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1767702p11583686).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I just saw that you edited and added your comment. You found it well.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Sorry about that, and I correct it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Solutions of Diophantine equations in Natural numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263647/solutions-of-diophantine-equations-in-natural-numbers) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%5E4-2y%5E2%3D1%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aintegers&p=1).

Comment: @JohnOmielan Yes and Thank you so much